# How to read test data from excel in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I try to read test data from excel file and that data is use in sendkeys.
This is my code but it gives me error in line `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream (new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\testdata.xls"));` that The constructor `FileInputStream(File)` is undefined.
Can somebody help me.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; 
import jxl.Workbook; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; 
import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;
```

...

```
WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[data-target='#login-box']"));
login.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("samplefile.xls"));
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream (new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\testdata.xls"));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
//Workbook wBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("E:\\Testdata\\ShellData.xls"));
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
//get sheet
// jxl.Sheet Sheet = wBook.getSheet(0); 
int i;
//Now in application i have given my Username and Password input in following way
driver.findElement(By.id("uname_h")).sendKeys((CharSequence[]) Sheet.getCell(0, i));
driver.findElement(By.id("password_h")).sendKeys((CharSequence[]) Sheet.getCell(1, i));
driver.findElement(By.id("health_btn")).click();
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not working? Is an exception thrown? Unexpected results? Please tell us what you expect and what you get as the crystal ball is not working very reliable. ;-)

Comment: Can you show us the import statements? The constructor FileInputStream(File) is valid if used with the correct file-class. Also the complete stacktrace could be useful.

Comment: import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import jxl.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to instantiate the `FileInputStream` with a `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File` which is indeed undefined. If you need that import then you should change the problematic line to

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream (new java.io.File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\testdata.xls"));
```